# Find array key in objects array given an attribute value

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an objects array like this:

```
Array
(
    [945] => member Object
        (
            [id] => 13317
            [name] => Test 999
            [last_name] => Test 999
        )

    [54] => member Object
        (
            [id] => 13316
            [name] => Manuel
            [last_name] => Maria parra
        )

    [654] => member Object
        (
            [id] => 13315
            [name] => Byron 
            [last_name] => Castillo
        )

    [656] => member Object
        (
            [id] => 13314
            [name] => Cesar
            [last_name] => Vasquez
        )
)
```

I need to remove one of these objects according to an attribute value.
For example, I want to remove from the array the object id 13316.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Here is the functional approach:

```
$neededObjects = array_filter(
    $objects,
    function ($e) use ($idToFilter) {
        return $e->id != $idToFilter;
    }
);
```

Comment: dude the array is the first array_filter parameter, not the last! http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Perfect, worth noting that you can define the closure like `function ($e) use ($id_to_find) {` to be able to pass a var that contains the ID to search for.  Maybe I'm the only one that didn't know this though ;) [PHP Manual - Example 3](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Awsome.. thanks :D I used it to compare if array elements arrayA present in array of objects.      $arrayA=array(14,18,30,50);  $neededObjects = array_filter(
    $objects,
    function ($e) {
        return  in_array ($e->id,$arrayA);
    }
);

Answer (score 4):

```
function filter_by_key($array, $member, $value) {
   $filtered = array();
   foreach($array as $k => $v) {
      if($v->$member != $value)
         $filtered[$k] = $v;
   }
   return $filtered;
}

$array = ...
$array = filter_by_key($array, 'id', 13316);
```

Comment: If you redefine your function in terms of `array_filter` you'll earn my up vote :D Perhaps `filter_by_key` would be a better name.

Comment: @erisco, Regardless I changed it to `filter_by_key` as you recommended.

Comment: My intuition is that a member is a value, so filter_by_member would return all members that satisfy a predicate based on its value (just a regular filter). Another bit of convention is that a filter function usually only excludes things that *do not* satisfy a predicate. That is why I'd like to see the function rewritten using array_filter, and why not since array_filter is already predefined to do what you need?

Answer (score 4):

**Use array search function :**

```
//return array index of searched item

$key = array_search($search_value, array_column($list, 'column_name'));

$list[key]; //return array item
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there is already plenty solutions given, I suggest an alternative to using the array:

```
$storage = new SplObjectStorage;  // create an Object Collection
$storage->attach($memberObject);  // add an object to it
$storage->detach($memberObject);  // remove that object
```

You could make this into a custom `MemberCollection` class with Finder methods and other utility operations, e.g.

```
class MemberCollection implements IteratorAggregate
{
    protected $_storage;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_storage = new SplObjectStorage;
    }
    public function getIterator()
    {
        return $this->_storage;
    }
    public function addMember(IMember $member)
    {
        $this->_storage->attach($member);
    }
    public function removeMember(IMember $member)
    {
        $this->_storage->detach($member);
    }
    public function removeBy($property, $value)
    {
        foreach ($this->_storage as $member) {
            if($member->$property === $value) {
                $this->_storage->detach($member);
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Might be overkill for your scenario though.

Answer (score 0):

```
   foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
      if ($value->id==13316) {
         unset($array[$key]);
         break;
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have edited my answer, my keys are not sorted, I mean, they are not 0, 1, 2, 3 ... please take a new look at my awnser, I changed the array keys, thk!