# get value from array if mached

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

**i have array sometimes returned as one location or many locations 
i want to check array with the variable $location = egypt ; 
and if find this value retun this array from all this locations array**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [count] => 2
    [query] => Cairo
    [locations] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1190
                    [name] => Cairo, Egypt - 341 hotels
                    [country_name] => Egypt
                    [country_code] => EG
                    [state_name] => 
                    [state_code] => 
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 11016
                    [name] => Cairo, GA, United States - 4 hotels
                    [country_name] => United States
                    [country_code] => US
                    [state_name] => {"en":"Georgia"}
                    [state_code] => GA
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: First of - you have object, not array. Next - show, please, what did you tried. Also desired result sample is needed.

Comment: Do an [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) on  $topLevelObject->locations

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find array key in objects array given an attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166198/find-array-key-in-objects-array-given-an-attribute-value)

Answer (score 0):

```
function locationReturn($locationArray){
  $result = array();
  foreach($locationArray as $value){
    if($value['country_name'] == 'Egypt')
     return $value;
  }
  return $result; // return empty array if not getting
}
```