# PHP: find an object in array using attributes array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find an object (Or multiple objects) inside an array using another attributes array

i came across this question [Find array key in objects array given an attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166198/find-array-key-in-objects-array-given-an-attribute-value) and found great solution, i modified it a bit and end up with this:

```
//$array = array(object1,object2,object3);
//$attributes example array('first_name'=>'value','last_name'=>'value');
function filter_by_key($array, $attributes) {
   $filtered = array();
   foreach($array as $k => $v) {
      //if($v->$member != $value) //stuck here 
         $filtered[$k] = $v;
   }
   return $filtered;
}
```

How can modify that line to test all the given $attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention that **get_object_vars** see only *public* attributes. May be more effective **ReflectionClass::getProperties**.

Coded in editor, to test:

```
//$array = array(object1,object2,object3);
//$attributes example array('first_name'=>'value','last_name'=>'value');
function filter_by_key($array, $attributes) {
   $filtered = array();
   foreach($array as $obj) {
       $found = true;
       $obj_attr = get_object_vars($obj);
       foreach($attributes as $attr => $val){
           if(!isset($obj_attr[$attr]) || $obj_attr[$attr] != $val){
               $found = false;
               break;
           } 
       } 
       if($found){
         $filtered[$k] = $obj;
       }
   }
   return $filtered;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

array_filter is dedicated method to filter arrays:

```
function createObject($first, $last) {
   $object = new StdClass;
   $object->first_name = $first;
   $object->last_name = $last;
   return $object;
}

$array = array( createObject('value1', 'value1'), createObject('value', 'value'));
$attributes = array('first_name'=>'value','last_name'=>'value');

var_dump(array_filter($array, function ($element) use($attributes) {
   foreach ($attributes as $attribute => $value) {
        if (is_object($element) 
            && property_exists($element, $attribute) 
            && $element->{$attribute} !== $value
        ) {
            return false;
        }
   }
   return true;
}));
```

output:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(5) "value"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(5) "value"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//$array = array(object1,object2,object3);
//$attributes = array('first_name'=>'value','last_name'=>'value');
$filtered = array_filter($array,
        // that's the callback function that filters the object 
        function ($e){
            global $attributes; // we need to make $attributes 
                                // recognizable in the scope
            foreach($attributes as $k => $v){
                if($e[$k] == $v){ // only if object $e from the array has 
                                  // the same attribute and same value
                    return true;  // add this object to $filtered
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Hope It will help you

Array
(
    [945] => member Object
        (
            [id] => 13317
            [name] => Test 999
            [last_name] => Test 999
        )
    [54] => member Object
        (
            [id] => 13316
            [name] => Manuel
            [last_name] => Maria parra
        )
    [654] => member Object
        (
            [id] => 13315
            [name] => Byron 
            [last_name] => Castillo
        )
    [656] => member Object
        (
            [id] => 13314
            [name] => Cesar
            [last_name] => Vasquez
        )
)

```
function filter_by_key($array, $member, $attributes) {
$filtered = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (in_array($v->$member, $attributes)) {
        $filtered[$k] = $v;
    }
}
return $filtered;
```

}

```
$filterd = filter_by_key($array, 'id', array('13316','13317'));
```